# Best approach to create a web app for iOS

Tags: cordova

I am planning to write an iPhone app that uses HTML 5 to render some graphics for the data retrieved through a REST api on the web server.

I am considering two approaches:

1) create the html5 pages, the scripts, etc (basically the entire UI) on the web server and use UIWebView to open the pages.

2) use PhoneGap to include the pages and scripts in the app.

My questions are

1) Are both acceptable when I submit the app?

2) Can I embed all the files in the package and use UIWebView to open them on the client?If so, what advantage does PhoneGap offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Phonegap with success for a same kind of app. If your app really only use HTML5, Javascript and CSS3, the advantage does PhoneGap offer is that your will be able to create an Android app in the same time with no additional effort (except somme CSS bug you will encounter but no more than when you create a website).

My Phonegap app have been accepted on the Appstore with no problem. I really recommand Phonegap for the development of some "viewer" application that "render some graphics for the data retrieved through a REST api on the web server".

Comment: There are a few other things to consider when using PhoneGap with local html files

1) Access to device's features (such as camera, Accelerometer), even though some of them may be already supported in HTML5

2) Performance: don't need to download the scripts from the server.